# Comparing two common fields from two different tables on common attribute - custody rec

Tags: sql

My goal is to write a SQL query to perform a custody rec. Comparing securities held per source 1 and securities held per source 2.

Table 1 is from one source, Table 2 from another source. Both tables have a column `ISIN` which should have only unique elements that is a unique identifier for certain traded securities. `Amount` represents the number of securities held for the given `ISIN` in column `ISIN` based on source #1 in Table 1 and similarly from source #2 in table 2.

For example, in Table 1 say we are holding 1,000 shares of
`US-000402625-0` and Table 2 also shows that we are holding 1,000 shares of that security:

Table 1

| ISIN | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| US-000402625-0 | 1,000 |
| US-000341234-0 | 2,000 |

Table 2:

| ISIN | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| US-000402625-0 | 1,000 |
| US-000341234-0 | 500 |
| US-000433045-0 | 200 |

The result that I am trying to achieve from the SQL query is the following table:

| ISIN | AmountA | AmountB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| US-000402625-0 | 1,000 | 1,000 |
| US-000341234-0 | 2,000 | 500 |
| US-000433045-0 | NULL | 200 |

where `AmountA` is the alias for the column `Amount` corresponding to the `amount` held for each `ISIN` from Table 1, and `AmountB` similarly from Table 2. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Those markdown tables are such a screen height waste...

Comment: Sorry my first time in the forum, will learn how to do it next time. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safe way, `UNION ALL` and `GROUP BY`. Will handle duplicate ISIN's in a table.

```
select isin, sum(amounta), sum(amountb)
from
(
  select isin, amount amounta, null as amountb from table1
  union all
  select isin, null, amount from table2
) dt
group by isin
```

You can also do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Will probably not handle duplicate ISIN's as desired.

```
select t1.isin, t1.amount amounta, t2.amount amountb
from table1 t1
  full outer join table2 t2 on t1.isin = t2.isin
```